# How to completely hide the ui in my android app

Tags: android

I want to hide all ui from my app but when i try to do that with the code below when i enter the activity the ui loads and immediately hide it but i want it to be invisible all the time.

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        hideSystemUI();
    }
    private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
    // except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
    private void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Comment: Do you really mean you want to hide all UI, or you just want to hide the system UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it a bit late. Call `hideSystemUI();` in `onCreate`. It should work.

Comment: I try your solution and my problem is fixed but isn't that gonna slow down my app?

Comment: No it won't slow down, you will be calling this method one way or another.